# Edit property of an object in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have a class `itemCollection` that stores information about purchases. This class has array `_items` as property where purchases are stores. When user adds new purchase in cart this class using `addItem` method that adds that item in `_items` property if its already has this item this method iterates `quantity` property if not adds new item in array.

Problem is that instead of adding new item in array when other item is chosen its keeps incrementing quantity property of a first item that was added.

`cartCollection` class (object):

```js
var cartCollection = {
    _items: [],
    addItem: function(obj) {
      'use strict';
      var purchase = {
        item: {
          id: obj.id,
          name: obj.name,
          price: obj.price
        },
        thisItemTotal: obj.price,
        quantity: 1
      };
      var result = _.findWhere(this._items, purchase.item.id);
      console.log(result);
      if (typeof result != 'undefined') {
        //console.log(result);
        var index = _.findIndex(this._items, {
          id: result.item.id
        });
        //console.log(index);
        result.quantity++;
        this._items[index] = result;
        this._itemTotalPrice();
      } else if (typeof result === 'undefined') {
        console.log("Im was called!");
        this._items.push(purchase);
        console.log(this._items);
      }
    },
    ...
```

Comment: I know, this is habit after other languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since purchase doesn't have an ID, but has an "item" with an ID, The correct find statement should be:

```
var result = _.find(this._items, function(item) {
   return item.item.id == purchase.item.id;
});
```

It might be better to rename `_items` to `_purchases` in order to disambiguate

The complete code should be something like:

```
addItem: function(obj) {
  'use strict';
  var purchase = {
    item: _.pick(obj, 'id', 'name', 'price')
    thisItemTotal: obj.price,
    quantity: 1
  };

  var result = _.find(this._items, function(item) {
    return item.item.id == purchase.item.id;
  });

  console.log(result);

  if (result) {
    result.quantity++;
    this._itemTotalPrice();
  }
  else {
    console.log("Im was called!");
    this._items.push(purchase);
    console.log(this._items);
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Your findWhere statement is broken. It should be:

```
var result = _.findWhere(this._items, {id:purchase.item.id});
```

Good luck

Comment: Now it adds new object but not increments quantity.

Comment: you're pushing `purchase` instead of `purchase.item`

Comment: Did I understood you correctly I'm need to use it like this: `this._items.push(purchase.item);`? If that so now im getting: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: it's pretty impossible to answer your questions without all the context. I am going to leave it at this and wish you good luck.